# API with Query Params

Tags: jquery, html, json, api

When I run the code below I get no errors a list of URL's

```
$(document).ready(function($) {


 const app = document.getElementById('theTable');

 const container = document.createElement('div');
 container.setAttribute('class', 'container');


 app.appendChild(container);

 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var theMainAPI = '/Aud/1234/run/123456/result/pages/'
 request.open('GET', theMainAPI, true);
 request.onload = function () {

var x = document.createElement("TABLE");
x.setAttribute("id", "myTable");
document.body.appendChild(x);

// Begin accessing JSON data here
   var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
   if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      data.forEach(theUrls => {
      var y = document.createElement("TR");
      y.setAttribute("id", "myTr");
      document.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(y);
      var z = document.createElement("TD");
      var t = document.createTextNode(theUrls);
      z.appendChild(t);
      document.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(z);
   });
   } else {
     const errorMessage = document.createElement('marquee');
     errorMessage.textContent = `Gah, it's not working!`;
     app.appendChild(errorMessage);
   }
}

request.send();
});
```

I want to use those URL's as query params to generate a new set of API's and get values from that.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {


 const app = document.getElementById('theTable');

 const container = document.createElement('div');
 container.setAttribute('class', 'container');


 app.appendChild(container);

 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var theMainAPI = '/Aud/1234/run/123456/result/pages/page?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.abc.com%2Fat-work%2F'
 request.open('GET', theMainAPI, true);
 request.onload = function () {

var x = document.createElement("TABLE");
x.setAttribute("id", "myTable");
document.body.appendChild(x);

// Begin accessing JSON data here
   var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
   if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      data.forEach(theUrls => {
      var y = document.createElement("TR");
      y.setAttribute("id", "myTr");
      document.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(y);
      var z = document.createElement("TD");
      var t = document.createTextNode(theUrls.parent);
      z.appendChild(t);
      document.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(z);
   });
   } else {
     const errorMessage = document.createElement('marquee');
     errorMessage.textContent = `Gah, it's not working!`;
     app.appendChild(errorMessage);
   }
}

request.send();
});
```

I am getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function at 
XMLHttpRequest.request.onload
```

I want to use the URL I get from the first block code above and add it to:

```
  /Aud/1234/run/123456/result/pages/ + "page?url=" + https%3A%2F%2Fwww.abc.com%2Fat-work%2F'
```

I have API data for the API call with query parameters but I am just unable to call the data and I am getting the error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I might be wrong here but i think you are suppose to read the response from the response like `request.responseText` and not `JSON.parse(this.response)`. Can you try this?And you can probably checkout the fetch api since it i easier to work with than XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be because of

```
var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
```

you can try replacing it with

```
var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText)
```

Since the response is stored in the reponseText property. And check whether the response you get one with query params is actually an array. Since forEach exists only on an array.

You have done a good job. But, since you are using jquery you can probably reduce your code alot further by taking advantage of jquery methods more.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#theTable').append($('div', {class:"container"}));
  //i am using fetch here you can use jquery alternative $.get also
   fetch('/Aud/1234/run/123456/result/pages/')
        .then(function(response) {
            if(response.ok) {
              return response.json();
            } else {
               throw Error(`Request rejected with status ${res.status}`);
            }
        })
        .then(function(data){
             if(!Array.isArray(data)) {
                  throw Error('Response is not in correct format')
             }
             let allRowHTML = data.reduce(function(rowHTML, URI) {
                 rowHTML.concat(`<tr><td>${URI}</td></tr>`)
             }, '');
             $('#myTable').append(myTable);
        })
        .catch(funtion (err) {
          console.error(JSON.stringify(err));
        })
})
```

Comment: Thank you but what is `res` in `res.ok`?

Comment: sorry its supposed to be response typo.